# ++ operator not working in guessing game?

Tags: c++

I am making a silly guessing game from a tutorial. I need the loop to exit if there have been 10 guesses and no correct answer. Each valid guess (valid user input for int) needs to update the guess_input variable which is 0 at the start.
The print_guesses function is meant to list the guesses the user inputted after he or she guesses at max 10 times or gets it right. This is the code in which I am trying to accomplish an updating of the guess_input (or number of guesses attempted) ...

```
for (int i = 0; true; i++)
{


std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input];

if (guesses [guess_input] != answer && std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input] )
   { guess_input++;
   }
```

It appears the guess_input is not updating in the game function because the print_guesses function does not list all of the valid guesses put in by the user.
Also, the game function will allow you to guess about 20 times before finally executing the code I want to execute after 10 incorrect yet valid inputs ...

```
if (guess_input == 9)

   { std:: cout << "Sorry! You lost, your guesses were \n \n";
    print_guesses (guesses, guess_input);
   }
```

I also posted to the full code at the bottom if it is of any help.

Thanks :)

```
void game ()
{

srand(time(NULL));

int guesses [10];
int answer = rand () % 501;
int guess_input = 0;
    std:: cout << answer;
    std:: cout << "\n \n";
    std:: cout << "Guess the answer";
    std:: cout << "\n \n";

for (int i = 0; true; i++)
{


std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input];

if (guesses [guess_input] != answer && std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input] )
   { guess_input++;
   }

if (std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input])
{
}
    else { std:: cout << "Enter a valid choice \n \n";
         std:: cin.clear ();
         std:: cin.ignore ();
         }

if (guess_input == 0 && guesses [guess_input] == answer)
    {std:: cout << "Correct! No incorrect guesses!";
    break;
    }

if (guesses [guess_input] == answer)
   { std:: cout << "Correct! Your guesses were \n \n";
    print_guesses (guesses, guess_input);
   }

if (guess_input == 9)

   { std:: cout << "Sorry! You lost, your guesses were \n \n";
    print_guesses (guesses, guess_input);
   }
}

}
```

**ENTIRE CODE IF IT HELPS**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void print_guesses (int array_parameter [], int array_count)
{
   std:: cout << "Your guesses were \n \n";
   for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i ++)

       {
        std:: cout << array_parameter [i] << '\n';
       }
}


void game ()
{

srand(time(NULL));

int guesses [10];
int answer = rand () % 501;
int guess_input = 0;
    std:: cout << answer;
    std:: cout << "\n \n";
    std:: cout << "Guess the answer";
    std:: cout << "\n \n";

for (int i = 0; true; i++)
{


std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input];

if (guesses [guess_input] != answer && std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input] )
   { guess_input++;
   }

if (std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input])
{
}

if (guess_input == 0 && guesses [guess_input] == answer)
    {std:: cout << "Correct! No incorrect guesses!";
    break;
    }

if (guesses [guess_input] == answer)
   { std:: cout << "Correct! Your guesses were \n \n";
    print_guesses (guesses, guess_input);
   }

if (guess_input == 9)

   { std:: cout << "Sorry! You lost, your guesses were \n \n";
    print_guesses (guesses, guess_input);
   }
}

}

void menu ()

{

while (true)

{
  short menu_input;

  double long test_variable;

  std:: cout << "Select 1 to play \n \n";

  std:: cout << "Select 9 to quit \n \n";

  std:: cin >> menu_input;

        if (menu_input == 1)

        { game ();
        }

        if (menu_input == 9)

        { std:: cout << "See ya!";
          break;
        }

        else

        {std:: cout << "Enter a valid menu choice \n \n";
        std:: cin.clear ();
        std:: cin.ignore ();
        }

}

}

int main ()

{

menu ();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input];

if (guesses [guess_input] != answer && std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input] )
   { guess_input++;
   }

if (std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input])
{
}
```

This code reads in three guesses, once in each block of code. But it only increments `guess_input` once. If the intent was to increment `guess_input` once for each guess, this code simply doesn't do that.

Comment: No sir, the intent is to only increment ```guess_input``` for one of them which is the one it is listed in but it is not incrementing in that one block, or so it appears, or so is my theory. I am trying to make it increment only when the guess is incorrect and valid (not a character or symbol)

Comment: @UVBakesandBeyond You wanted to read in three inputs and increment `guess_input` only once? If so, why does your question say that's not what you wanted to do?

Comment: I stated I want to increase the ```guess_input``` when the guess is incorrect but valid.

Comment: @UVBakesandBeyond Right, and this code doesn't do that because it reads *three* guesses and can increment `guess_input` at most once. Do you see that this code reads three guesses? Do you see that this code increments `guess_input` at most once?

Comment: I suppose I am mistaken sir. Perhaps the following is incorrect... I believe this code updates the array that is ```guesses``` one index at a time by using the ```guess_input``` variable as an index location setter (for lack of a better term) with each time the following code is true ```if (guesses [guess_input] != answer && std:: cin >> guesses [guess_input] ) ``` I don't understand why this wouldn't work if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @UVBakesandBeyond Do you understand that the code snippet above reads *three* guesses from `cin`? The code `cin >> guesses [guess_input]` reads a guess from `cin` and that code appears *three* times, so it reads *three* guesses.

Comment: So each time that ```cin >> guesses [guess_input]``` is written it is asking for an input? If so I did not know that. I thought that inside of an if parenthesis, it simply meant that, if the input is valid then it is true and the following code in curly brackets executes.

Comment: @UVBakesandBeyond If you think about it, that can't possibly be right. If that were true, you could never read more than one thing. How would it know when you wanted to read something new and when you wanted to test some previous input if it's exactly the same code every time?

Comment: I do not understand what the term "reads" means in this context but I understand now that ```cin >> guesses [guess_input]``` will always ask for input, I think I was able to solve the issue trying something else after learning that from you, but I will have to test it more. I might have mistaken that from a tutorial, I understand that would be odd if it worked that way.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue, thank you very much for your patience and knowledge sir. I really appreciate it :)